# Can I script Data Classifications in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am looking into [SQL Data Classifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-database/sql-database-data-discovery-and-classification) in SQL Azure.

To do this I must log onto the **Azure Portal** for each **database** and configure the **Data Classifications**. I have 100 databases for seperate clients all with the same schema.

Is there a way I can Script these classifications using SQL?

I'm guessing there is a sys table where these classicfication tags are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received the following answer from the  SQL Security Vulnerability Assessment Team at Microsoft: "Such scripting capabilities are coming for Data Classification soon". At this time there are no scripting capabilities.